# Align Input fields in HTML without css

Tags: html, input

Trying to get the input fields of my html to align up with the other input fields.

Is there a way to make it aligned without using CSS?

This is what I have :
Name:|-----Input-------|

Password:|-----Input-------|

Confirm password:|-----Input-------|

Email:|-----Input-------|

Phone:|-----Input-------|

Trying to make it like this:

Name:.....................|-----Input-------|

Password:..............|-----Input-------|

Confirm password:|-----Input-------|

Email:.....................|-----Input-------|

Phone:...................|-----Input-------|

(without the dots)

Code:

```
<form>
    <label>Name:</label>
    <input type="text" name="namefield" align="center"> <br /> 
    <label><br>Password: </label>
    <input type="password" name="pwdfield"> <br /> 
    <label><br>Confirm password: </label>
    <input type="password" name="cpwdfield"> <br />
    <label><br>Email: </label>
    <input type="email" name="email"> <br /> 
    <label><br>Phone: </label> 
    <input type="tel" name="phone"> <br />
    <br>
    <input type="submit" value="Register" />
</form>
```

Comment: you can use a `<table />`

Comment: http://www.w3schools.com/html/html_tables.asp. Use table

Answer (score 0):

Using the table tag without borders allows one to align textboxes without css.

```html
<FORM>    
<TABLE frame="box">
  <TR><TD>Your name</TD>        <TD><INPUT TYPE="TEXT" NAME="name" SIZE="25"></TD>      </TR>
  <TR><TD>Password</TD>         <TD><INPUT TYPE="TEXT" NAME="pwdfield" SIZE="25"></TD>  </TR>
  <TR><TD>Confirm password</TD> <TD><INPUT TYPE="TEXT" NAME="cpwdfield" SIZE="25"></TD> </TR>  
  <TR><TD>E-mail</TD>           <TD><INPUT TYPE="TEXT" NAME="email" SIZE="25"></TD>     </TR>
  <TR><TD>Phone</TD>            <TD><INPUT TYPE="TEXT" NAME="phone" SIZE="25"></TD>     </TR>  
</TABLE>
<P><INPUT TYPE="SUBMIT" VALUE="Register" NAME="B1"></P>
</FORM>
```