# HTML input field alignment

Tags: html, css

How do you align input fields without using css or anything advanced? the first image is the required output and the second one is my output[image: this is the required output][image: this is my output]

i tried adding a bunch of spaces using &nbsp but it didnt seem right and the code looekd untidy

Comment: What's wrong with using CSS?

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29464349/align-input-fields-in-html-without-css

Answer (score -3, accepted):

You can use a traditional html table and set the border to zero.

```
<table border="0">
...
</table>
```

Comment: The `border` attribute is [deprecated](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/table#attr-border), though.